# Расширения PHP - вопрос к гуру

Tags: apache, php.ini, php, сервер

Скомпилировал **Apache PHP** из предложенных на выбор пакетов и расширений.
После проверки `echo phpinfo();` проверил, какие установлены и включены (curl, gd2, mcrypt, sockets).

Но, в логах пишет, что не найдены **dll** для расширений:

> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_curl.dll
>
> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll
>
> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_mcrypt.dll
>
> no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_sockets.dll
>
> PHP Warning:  Cannot load module
> 'pdo_cassandra' because required
> module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown
> on line 0

Стоит версия **PHP 5.5.16**.

Путь к расширениям в *php.ini* указана правильно. Там действительно нет этих *.dll.
Какие пути решения для этого есть?
Будет ли правильно просто загрузить туда недостающие dll (версия)?

PS: **rootcode** перестал, что ли, работать?

Comment: Да, просто положите эти расширения в эту папку, и потом апач перезапустить надо.

Comment: > PS: rootcode перестал, что ли, работать?

месяца так два-три назад его объединили с хэшкодом

Comment: А если версии dll не подойдут? Где их свежие найти можно для PHP 5.5.16?

Comment: Дело происходит в винде? Если нет, то никаких dll и не должно быть.

Comment: Вопрос решен, стоит CentOS. Осталась одна задача, поставить PDO cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А тебе действительно нужно работать с касандрой? Эта СУБД конечно интересная, но специфическая и не сильно популярная. Может проще убрать этот модуль из конфигов?

Модуль pdo_cassandra должен зависеть от модуля pdo и, скорее всего, от какой-нибудь бибилотеки самой касандры. В репозиториях centos кажется нет ни самой касандры, ни её модулей для php, но возможно я просто не там искал.

Пара советов общего характера:

1) Переносить конфиги из windows в *nix -- плохая идея. Кроме приколов с dll/so могут быть и другие подводные грабли. Лучше сразу настраивать софт на месте отталкиваясь от предустановленных конфигов.

2) Если у веб-сервера будет больше десятка-другого посетителей в день то стоит поставить nginx перед apache. А ещё лучше поставить apache один только nginx и php-fpm (реализация FastCGI для php). Конечно если нет каких-то явных показаний к использованию именно его. Apache старый, ему пора на пенсию.